# How to get the text within a tag without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser

I'm looking at an example on this [Getting value from table cell in javascript...not jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072233/getting-value-from-table-cell-in-javascript-not-jquery) page where someone showed how to grab text from a table in JavaScript:

```
var refTab=document.getElementById("ddReferences") 
var  ttl; 
// Loop through all rows and columns of the table and popup alert with the value 
// /content of each cell. 
for ( var i = 0; i<refTab.rows.length; i++ ) { 
  var row = refTab.rows.item(i); 
  for ( var j = 0; j<row.cells.length; j++ ) { 
    var col = row.cells.item(j);
    alert(col.firstChild.innerText); 
  } 
}
```

I'm wondering, if I wanted to simply grab the text in the cell of row 1, column 1, could I not do the following? If not, why not?

```
var myText = document.getElementById("ddReferences").rows.item(0).cells.item(0).firstChild.innerText;
```

It doesn't work when I try it in my webpage I'm trying to create. (Yes, I'm aware of a thing called JQuery. I know someone is going to tell me to learn it. Maybe I will some day.)

Comment: It works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2MLSZ/

Comment: Actually, I *can* reproduce the problem. It works in Chrome and IE, but doesn't work in FireFox, which I'm presuming is what the OP is using. I tried to post an answer, but I couldn't because the question was mistakenly closed as irreproducible. Nominating for reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using FireFox? [**innerText** doesn't work in FireFox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/764196) (see the orange "Helpful Reply").

The linked Mozialla Support Forum post and the blog post it refers to both recommend using **textContent** in the place of **innerText**. While this will work fine for one line of simple text, be aware that they are *not the same*. **textContent** returns the text within the element as it's written in the source (ignoring tags), whereas **innerText** returns the text as it's rendered on the page.

For example, with the following HTML

```html
<table id="ddReferences">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>foo bar</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

both

```javascript
document.getElementById("ddReferences").rows.item(0).cells.item(0).firstChild.innerText
```

and

```javascript
document.getElementById("ddReferences").rows.item(0).cells.item(0).firstChild.textContent
```

give you:

```html
foo bar
```

However, with this HTML:

```html
<table id="ddReferences">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>foo<br>bar</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**innerText** gives you:

```html
foo
bar
```

whereas **textContent** gives you:

```html
foobar
```

...and with this HTML:

```html
<table id="ddReferences">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>
        foo
        bar
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**innerText** gives you

```html
foo bar
```

whereas **textContent** gives you

```html
        foo
        bar
```

Do some experimenting with a fiddle and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a non-standard MS property, and not supported on some browsers.

The standard more-or-less equivalent is [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).

Then, the following should work:

```
document.getElementById("ddReferences")
    .rows.item(0)
        .cells.item(0)
            .firstChild
                .textContent;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2MLSZ/1/)