# How to get text from HtmlTableCellElement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working on a simple jquery tic-tac-toe project. I'm trying to iterate through the board and save the values of each cell in an array, but can't figure out how to access the text inside each td.  I've tried .text() and .value() but both return undefined

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Tic Tac Toe</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="40">
            <tr>
                <td data-x="0" data-y="0">Test</td>
                <td data-x="1" data-y="0"></td>
                <td data-x="2" data-y="0"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-x="0" data-y="1"></td>
                <td data-x="1" data-y="1"></td>
                <td data-x="2" data-y="1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-x="0" data-y="2"></td>
                <td data-x="1" data-y="2"></td>
                <td data-x="2" data-y="2"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="games"></div>
        <div id="message"></div>
        <button id="save">Save Game</button>
        <button id="previous">Show Previous Games</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

tic-tac-toe.js:

```
function getBoard(){
    board = [];
    $.each($("td"), function(index, cell){
        board.push(cell); //Need to return contents of cell
    });
    alert(board);
}
```

Comment: `rd.push($(this).text());` instead of `rd.push(cell);`

Comment: That did it!  Super simple, thank you

Answer (score 5):

Try this:-

Use this `cell.innerHTML` instead of `cell`

```
        function getBoard() {
            board = [];
            $.each($("td"), function (index, cell) {
                board.push(cell.innerHTML); //Need to return contents of cell
            });
            alert(board);
        }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use .text()

```
 $.each("td", function(index, cell) {
   board.push($(cell).text()); //Need to return contents of cell
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way, explained on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072366/6356627

```
function GetCellValues() {
        var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
        for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
            for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
                alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
            }
        }
    }
```